API call not happening if same payload object is set with setState - React Query
So I am currently learning react- query in my company and I am converting from redux-saga to react query.
I have a transaction history page which has some filters. User can open the filter, select some options and click on apply button to apply those filters. This triggers an api call with all those filters passed in the api endpoint query params.
So initially when page loads we do an api call and get 15 transactions and they are shown on the screen without filters. Now for filtering what I am doing is, I have create some states that hold the current filter options selected by the user and one payload useState that gets set when user clicks on apply button.
I am passing this payload state in the dependency of my queryKey.
So what happens is whenever user clicks the apply button, i call setPayload which sets the new payload and triggers the queryFn, gets me new filtered data and I use it.
Now the issue I am facing is,
Suppose our payload looks like {type : '1'} currently. And user selects option "2" which makes it {type : '2'} . Clicking on apply will pass the query fn type as 2. Now here's the catch, if user again opens the filter and selects type : '2' and clicks on apply button, the payload would again look like {type : '2' } . In this case react would not rerender the component as same payload is being set and hence api call wont happen.
Even if I change the reference and make it rerender then also api call is not happening i don't know why.
I want a system when even if user selects the same option, it should trigger the api call and get me latest data.
import './App.css';
import TodoCard from './components/TodoCard';
import { todo } from './types/todo';
import {  QueryClient, useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import React from 'react';
const queryClient = new QueryClient();
function App2() {
  const [payload,setState] = React.useState({type : 1});

  const fetchTodos = async ({ queryKey }: { queryKey : [],pageParam: number }) => {
    console.log("State received is at fetchtodos", payload)
    
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_page=${payload.type}`
    );
    return res.json();
  };


  React.useEffect(() => {
      console.log("state change ")
  }, [payload])


  const {
    isFetching,
    data,
    status,
    error,
  } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['todos',payload],
    queryFn: fetchTodos,
    initialPageParam: 1,
    staleTime : 0,
    gcTime : Infinity,
    placeholderData : [],
  });
  const content = data && data.map((todo: todo) =>{
      return <TodoCard key={todo.id} todo={todo} />;
    }) 

  if (status === 'error') {
    return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <button onClick={()=>{setState((state)=>({...state,type : 2}))}}>Press</button>
      {isFetching && <h3>Loading...</h3>}
      {!isFetching && content}{' '}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App2;


Since I cannot share the codebase, This is nearest simulation to the problem. I want to call api even if same type is getting set.
I tried spreading the payload to cause a reference change, but still react query is not calling the api. I want the api call to happen even if user selects the same option and clicks on apply.
I also tried to manually call the api if same filter is applied, but that is also not solving the issue.

React query doesn't use referential equality when considering the query key, it does more or less a "JSON stringify with stable sorting of keys", so even a different object with the same payload will not trigger it. If you want to refetch with the same payload, useQuery provides a refetch method:
const { refetch } = useQuery()

return <button onClick={() => refetch()}>Click here to refresh</button>

If you wanted to only use payload in the queryKey, you could inject a "cache busting mechanism" - every time you change the payload, you increase some value by 1:
const [index, bust] = useReducer((i) => i + 1, 0)
const [payload, setPayload] = useState({})

const update = (arg) => {
  setPayload(args)
  bust()
}

useQuery({
  queryKey: [payload, index] // <--- index here will make it always refetch
})

This should work, but it looks strange to me.


I want a system when even if user selects the same option, it should trigger the api call and get me latest data.

The simplest solution to this is to compare payloads, and call refetch returned from useQuery if they are identical instead of setPayload:
const [payload,setState] = React.useState({type : 1});

const { data, refetch) = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['todos',payload],
}

<button onClick={() => {
  const newState = { ...state.type : 2 }
  if (isEqual(newState, state)) {
    refetch()
  } else {
    setState(newState)
  }
}>
  Press
</button>

